# Android BroadCastReceiver refresh all activities

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an issue using BroadCastreceiver to refresh activities in my application. I'm using a service which is doing some calculations and in `onDestroy()` method I'm doing this :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){        
    super.onDestroy();

    Intent intent = new Intent("finish");
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and in my activities I'm doing this :

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals("finish")) {
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                 TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                 Intent previewMessage = new Intent(Tutorial.this, Tutorial.class);
                 parentActivity.startChildActivity("Tutorial", previewMessage);

                 progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 sync.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync_icon2);

                 final SharedPreferences isLogged = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = isLogged.edit();
                 editor.putBoolean("getProgBar", false);
                 editor.commit();
            }               
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("finish"));
```

I have that function in all my activities and the problem is that if I change 2-3 of them before my service stop, after that I can see in my LogCat logs from other activities which has that function too, but I'm not currently on these activities. They are just somewhere in activity stack. But the thing that I can't understand is it reloading them (even if I can't see it visually) and how to prevent this kind of issues. I need to refresh only activity which I'm in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add these to your activities. You have to unregister your `broadcastreceiver` and register it again in your `onResume()` like this :

```
    @Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    YourActivity.this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.MyService");
    YourActivity.this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
```